# Directory not created with specified mode

Tags: ansible

**EDIT**: I made a stupid error of thought, I am running ansible through an asible docker base image. The directory is created but *in the container* where ansible is running and not on the host of ansible docker image

I am using ansible to create directories that are later used for docker mounts.

In the playbook I have the following:

```
  - name: Create DB mount point
    file:
      path: /mnt/sda1/bic-mounts/oracle-database
      state: directory
      directory_mode: "777"
      mode: "777"
```

I had to add the `directory_mode` parameter even though it is not documented in order to make it work: Looking at [this ansible issue](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/40676) from a few months ago it seems I am not the only one with that problem.

With that parameter the directory is created, however its mode is `755` and not `777`. It does not seem to be an issue with octal vs decimal (as it should not since it is a string, but who knows) since 777 in decimal is 1411 in octal.

Does anyone know what causes the permissions to be wrong? I couldn't find anything in the documentation preventing 777 but the need for `directory_mode` is also not documented :)

Answer (score 1):

I confirm that specifying the leading zero works:

```
  - name: Create DB mount point
    file:
      path: /mnt/sda1/bic-mounts/oracle-database
      state: directory
      mode: 0777
```

See [official documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/file_module.html):

> Mode the file or directory should be. For those used to /usr/bin/chmod remember that modes are actually octal numbers. You must either specify the leading zero so that Ansible's YAML parser knows it is an octal number (like 0644 or 01777) or quote it (like '644' or '0644' so Ansible receives a string and can do its own conversion from string into number. Giving Ansible a number without following one of these rules will end up with a decimal number which will have unexpected results. As of version 1.8, the mode may be specified as a symbolic mode (for example, u+rwx or u=rw,g=r,o=r).

Comment: That is a possibility, from the documentation I assumed it also works with a string and I dont have to include the leading 0. However the root cause is a stupid mistake, I will edit the question with it which will kinda make the whole question pointless

Comment: I see, go ahead and delete the question I guess.

Comment: If you are interested and dont get notified by the edit: I was running ansible through a docker image, the directory was created as I had specified but inside the container and not the host from where i started the image of course :)